# How to add some class to wordpress menu link?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, menu

Need to add a class to menu links, Wordpress 4.x. In backend panel I can only add classes to **<li>** containers, not to **<a>**. I tried to add class .getscroll to **<li>** and use jQuery script:

```
$('.getscroll a').addClass('scroll');
```

That doesn't work, and with document.ready too. The link still looks like **<a href="...">text</a>**. Is there any way to add class to **<a>**?

HTML code of menu:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="white-nav b-shadow first-nav navbar-style2">
    <div class="nav-inner">
        <div class="logo">
            <!-- Navigation Logo Link -->
            <a href="/" class="scroll">
                <img class="site_logo" src="/lg-logo.png" alt="L">              </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Mobile Menu Button -->
        <a class="mobile-nav-button colored"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        <!-- Navigation Menu -->
        <div class="nav-menu clearfix semibold">

            <ul id="menu-3021" class="nav uppercase font-primary">
                <li id="menu-item-2058" class="getscroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-2058"><a title="Who we are" href="/#about">Who we are</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-2059" class="getscroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-2059"><a title="What we do" href="/#what-we-do">What we do</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML here

Comment: If you can use CSS, then write in the style.css, for eg:  .myclass ul li a{color:#000 !important}

Comment: Your code *should* work. What kind of error are you getting in the console?

Comment: @rnevius «Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the default WordPress version of jQuery, which means `$` isn't defined (because jQuery is included in `no-conflict` mode). You need to modify your document ready function slightly:

```
(function($){
    $('.getscroll a').addClass('scroll');
})(jQuery);
```

Alternatively, you can replace the `$` with `jQuery`; so it becomes:

```
jQuery('.getscroll a').addClass('scroll');
```

Read more about [no-conflict mode in the Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: Great! Please select my answer to close up this question. Also, I highly recommend reading about `no-conflict` mode in the link I included.